# Python classmethod constructor inheritance with different signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pycharm, class-method

**TLDR;**
I am using a `@classmethod` as a constructor for my class, and I need to override it with a different signature for one specific child class that needs extra parameters. PyCharm gives a warning about overriding a method with different signature. I wonder whether it also applies to `@classmethod` constructors.

---

I am using the IDE PyCharm for my python project and I have received the following warning regarding the overriding of a method in a class:

> Signature of method [...] does not match signature of base method in class [...]

I understand this is related to the Liskov substitution principle, meaning objects of a parent class should always be replaceable by objects of a child class.

However, in my case I am overriding a `@classmethod` which is used as a constructor, following some sort of factory pattern. A simplification of my code would be as follows:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, common, data):
        self.common = common
        self.data = data
    @classmethod
    def from_directory(cls, data_dir, common):
        all_data = [load_data(data_file) for data_file in get_data_files(data_dir)]
        return [cls(common, data) for data in all_data]

class ChildA(Parent):
    def __init__(self, common, data, specific):
        super().__init__(common, data)
        self.specific = specific
    @classmethod
    def from_directory(cls, data_dir, common, specific):
        all_data = [load_data(data_file) for data_file in get_data_files(data_dir)]
        return [cls(common, data, specific) for data in all_data]
```

In this example, basically I have a parent class `Parent` with some common attribute that all child classes will inherit, and some particular child class `ChildA` which has an extra, subclass-specific attribute.

Since I am using the `@classmethod` as a constructor, I assume the Liskov principle does not apply, just in the same way that the `__init__()` method can be overridden with a different signature. However, the PyCharm warning has made me consider whether there is something I might have missed. I am not sure whether I am using the `@classmethod` in a sensitive way.

**My main question is then:** Is PyCharm being overzealous with its warnings here or is there any reason the pattern described above should be avoided?

Also, any feedback about any other design issues / misconceptions I might have is most welcome.

Comment: Since a classmethod may be called on the instance, it affects the observable behavior of the instance. LSP is about behavior of instances, so it applies for classmethod as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Fair point, is there any reasonable use case for calling a constructor method from an instance instead of the class?

Comment: @user3407000 I cannot think of any, but that is beside the point. A classmethod is callable from the instance, whether sensible or not. One could define a classbutnotinstancemethod to enforce such things, but current type checkers very, very likely won't get it. Honestly I would not worry about it, these edge cases are artefacts of the type system that are not critical in practice.

Comment: @bad_coder Actually I think it does, I somehow missed that when googling... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would refine your class method. There are really *two* class methods to provide here: one that creates an instance of the class from a data file, and one that produces a list of instances from the files in a directory (using the first class method). Further, the class methods shouldn't care about which arguments `cls` will need: it just passes on whatever it receives (with the exception of `data`, which it knows about and will provide or override with whatever it reads from a file).

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, common, data, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.common = common
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename, **kwargs):
        # If the caller provided a data argument,
        # ignore it and use the data from the file instead.
        kwargs['data'] = load_data(filename)
        return cls(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_directory(cls, data_dir, **kwargs):
        return [cls.from_file(data_file, **kwargs)
                for data_file in get_data_files(data_dir)]
        

class ChildA(Parent):
    def __init__(self, specific, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.specific = specific
```

Notice that you no longer need to override `Parent.from_directory`; it's already agnostic about what arguments it receives that are intended for `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution. Is there is any way to use type hinting to suggest the user which parameters to use separately for both the case of the parent and the child class?

Comment: Not really; the set of arguments expected by `cls` is necessarily dynamic, not static, information, because the value of `cls` itself is not static.

Comment: Hmm, I can see how using your method it is indeed necessarily dynamic, but by overriding the constructor method in the child classes that deviate from the standard behavior I think it can be statically defined, which I think would add clarity to the code. I guess it is a tradeoff, and my original question was about the reasons why this overriding should be avoided (possible drawbacks). I would mark this as accepted answer if you include those reasons or a pro/con comparison, although as per the comments to my question I think it might be a duplicate...